# Create messages conversation list

Tags: php, mysql, list, message

Ok, I am trying to build a conversation list in PHP of all the messages that a user has.
My database is setup where there are 4 fields, a sender ID, a receiver ID, a timestamp, and the message. My query returns every result where the receiver ID equals the current users ID. I only want to select only the first occurrences of every sender's ID. Ie:

```
==================================================
| Sender ID | Receiver ID |    Time    | Message |
==================================================
|     2     |      1      | 1373914164 |   test  | <--- this one
|     2     |      1      | 1373914155 | ..test  |
|     1     |      1      | 1373914134 |...test  | <--- this one
|     2     |      1      | 1373914111 |   test. |
|     1     |      1      | 1373914108 |   test..|
|     3     |      1      | 1373914102 |   test  | <--- this one
|     3     |      1      | 1373914101 |   test  |
==================================================
```

My idea is to filter the results in an array using PHP, but I'm just at a total brain fart here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SQL by sorting by Time and then limiting to 1

Something like

```
Select ....
ORDER BY Time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This doesn't return the results I'm looking for, just the single latest row. I need the first occurrence of every sender ID in the entire table.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the question, thought we were going per user on the query. In that case Java Devil's answer should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
SELECT *     -- Or what ever Columns
FROM aTab    -- Your table name
WHERE time IN (
   SELECT MAX(time) 
   FROM aTab
   WHERE R_id = 1 -- would help create better consistency
   GROUP BY S_ID)
AND R_id = 1
```

However, if the Receiver happens to (very unlikely I would think) receive messages at exactly the same time this could cause weird results

You can see it here with this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fc7e/8)

Comment: In your fiddle that query works perfect, but for some reason on my localhost server it just returns every row.. I implemented the query exactly and replaced the field names with those that correspond to the ones on my table.